# Moving object when is touched

Tags: java, libgdx

I use this code to move object:

```
 if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {             
        gameObject1.y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY() + 30;             
        gameObject1.x=Gdx.input.getX() + 30;   
    }
```

But in this case, object move when screen is touched.
In LibGdx is simple way to move object when this object is clickedd/pressed? Something like the code above?

Comment: You need to make another if statement that triggers when you touch on the object. For round object you can use centre + radius. Otherwise you need box collision.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is probably to use `scene2d` for this. It has a [hit detection](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#hit-detection) feature, based on an [event system](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#event-system) that you can use by attaching [listeners](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#inputlistener) to your `Actors`.

Another way would be to use [`Intersector`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) in a combination with [`Rectangle`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html) as your bounding box and do the hit detection yourself.